# Trying to get each array of unknown amount separately from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to get each array generated from the following foreach loop so I can then insert them in another array:

```
function twprp_criteria_field() {                

    $data = '';

    $criteria_string = get_post_meta( 50, 'twprp_site_criteria', true );

    $criteria = explode( ',', $criteria_string );

    foreach( $criteria as $key => $criterion ) {

        $data[] = array(
            'id' => sanitize_title_with_dashes( $criterion ),
            'title' => $criterion,
            'type' => 'slider',
            'step' => 0.5,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 10,
            'default' => '',
        );

    }

    return $data;

}
```

This returns:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => hello [title] => Hello [type] => slider [step] => 0.5 [min] => 1 [max] => 10 [default] => ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => good-bye [title] => Good Bye [type] => slider [step] => 0.5 [min] => 1 [max] => 10 [default] => ) 
)
```

The problem is I need the arrays to be separate but currently they are part of one parent array. I know I can use twprp_criteria_field()[0] and twprp_criteria_field()[1] to get the individual arrays, but I'm returning an unknown number of arrays. I'm sure I'm missing something easy, but I just can't see it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Do you want to loop over the all the arrays that are returned? Also please add a `php` tag.

Comment: Yes I want to loop over all the arrays that are returned and then insert them into a new array like this: `'fields' => array( twprp_criteria_field() )`. I do not want the Array() that wraps all the arrays returned, just each individual array [0], [1] etc. Does this make sense?

Comment: Use a foreach on the $data object to access each element in turn

Comment: I've tried this but it still groups the arrays in a parent array.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing and are looking for is a `for` loop:

```
$arr = twprp_criteria_field();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
  echo 'Id:' . $arr[$i]['id'] . " ";
  echo 'title:' . $arr[$i]['title'];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I get the "Array to string conversion" error as this converts the arrays to strings because of the `."\n"` - they need to rename arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't quite understand how to integrate this into the "fields" array, because it's echoing strings, not an array. And since you can only insert an array into an existing array this won't work.

Comment: @GhostPool This is how arrays work. The number indexes are there so you don't write over your previous value. They always have to have a parent array if there is more than one type of index